# Make <ALT> key not tab out from fullscreen application

Tags: unity, gnome, shortcut-keys, fullscreen, hud

So after the 15.04 update, the `ALT` key will pop up the Unity HUD even when a fullscreen application like a game has the main focus.

Is there any way to disable this? I tried changing the hotkey in `Unity Tweak Tool` to something else for the HUD that has `ALT` hotkey set to it. But that did not change anything. The `ALT` key will still spawn the HUD when I am having a fullscreen application open.