# How can I make "alt" not show the title bar for fullscreen (F11'd) applications?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, ubuntu-gnome, fullscreen

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Memory: 7.7GiB
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-5257U CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4 
Graphics: Intel® Iris 6100 (Broadwell GT3) 
OS type: 64-bit
Disk: 37.0 GB
Machine: Macbook Pro A5102
uname -a: Linux caleb-macbuntu 4.8.0-41-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 17:11:16 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
uname -r: 4.8.0-41-generic
```

Running Gnome.

When I fullscreen an app, such as VSCode, using "f11", the title bar disappears:

[image]

However, if I press alt (for hotkeys, desktop switching, whatever), the title bar appears:

[image]

I have explored the keybindings of apps and the system itself and haven't found any way to override this functionality.

How can I prevent this behavior?

EDIT: Please note this is not related to [Make <ALT> key not tab out from fullscreen application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618308/make-alt-key-not-tab-out-from-fullscreen-application?rq=1) . I am asking about the title bar appearing, not a unity GUI thing.

EDIT2: Other users were not able to override this outside of a given app: https://discuss.atom.io/t/alt-key-menu-bar-interaction-overrides-shortuts/9192/10